How to Send Emails Using Gmail API with Google OAuth in Node.js?
I am trying to send emails using the Gmail API in a Node.js backend. I've implemented Google OAuth 2.0 to obtain an authorization code and exchange it for an access token. However, I'm running into issues with the email-sending process. Below is my current setup:
Frontend Workflow:

User logs in via Google OAuth and grants email permissions.
I get an authorization code.
The code is sent to the backend for token exchange.

Backend code:
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const CLIENT_ID = "---googleusercontent.com";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "----";
const REDIRECT_URI = "----";

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

app.post("/exchange-code", async (req, res) => {
const { code } = req.body;

try {
  const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
  oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
  res.json(tokens);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error exchanging code for tokens:", error.message);
  res.status(500).send("Failed to exchange authorization code.");
}
});

app.post("/send-email", async (req, res) => {
const { accessToken, to, subject, message } = req.body;

try {
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: accessToken });

  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: oauth2Client });

  const email = `To: ${to}\nSubject: ${subject}\n\n${message}`;
  const base64EncodedEmail = Buffer.from(email)
    .toString("base64")
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_");

  const result = await gmail.users.messages.send({
    userId: "me",
    requestBody: {
      raw: base64EncodedEmail,
    },
  });

  res.json({ success: true, messageId: result.data.id });
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error sending email:", error.message);
  res.status(500).send("Failed to send email.");
}
});

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})


and in what kind of issues do you run into?
